# When do we need to use System.AppContext?

Tags: c#

Seems `AppContext` only has a property called `BaseDirectory`. But `Environment` class seems to have much more properties and methods.

So is `AppContext` being replaced by `Environment` class now?

Comment: A Good Question, what if i resolve the service via an IoC like Unity, will this context be still accessible across libraries, if so how is it handled.

Comment: Additionally, how can this appcontext be used when the services are delivered behind a load balancer?

Answer (score 13):

`AppContext` has been introduced with **.NET 4.6** thus it won't be replaced.

[MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/04/29/net-announcements-at-build-2015.aspx#dotnet46) says:

> **AppContext is a new compatibility feature that enables library writers
> to provide a uniform opt-out mechanism for new functionality for their
> users.** It established a loosley-coupled contract between components in
> order to communicate an opt-out request. This capability is typically
> important when a change is made to existing functionality. Conversely,
> there is already an implicit opt-in for new functionality.
>
> With AppContext, libraries define and expose compatibility switches,
> while code that depends on them can set those switches, to affect the
> library behavior. By default libraries provide the new functionality
> and only alter it (e.g. provide the old behavior) if the switch is
> set.

In summary, it provides functionality to deal with multiple versions of the same dll.

Code example is within the provided link.