# NullReferenceException when validating xml with .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I am testing switching from .NET version 4.5.1 to 4.6 and ran into an NullReferenceExceptionin the xsd validation when using an unique constraint on an optional attribute.

```
at System.Xml.Schema.KeySequence.ToString()
at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.EndElementIdentityConstraints(Object typedValue, String stringValue, XmlSchemaDatatype datatype)
at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.InternalValidateEndElement(XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo, Object typedValue)
at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessEndElementEvent()
at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()
at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
at ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This is stripped code which runs when targeting v4.5.x but fails with a NullReferenceException when using 4.6. (Tested on Win7 with VS2013 and VS2015). Is this legal in xml? Even if not it should raise some XmlException.

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Enumerations">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Enum" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="unique_EnumId_contraint">
      <xs:selector xpath="Enum"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Enumerations>
  <Enum />
  <Enum />
</Enumerations>
```

C# code:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.Schemas.Add(null, "enumerations.xsd");

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("enumerations.xml", settings))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = xmlReader.Depth * 4;
            Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't look like the Enum nodes have id's

Comment: That is on purpose to keep backward compatibility with previous formats. I could check the uniqueness in code but it should work like it did in 4.5.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this. Looks like a bug to me (`<rant>`.NET 4.6 has a lot...`</rant>`). You should report it to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

While this is fixed, you can check the source here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Schema/ConstraintStruct.cs,091791a9542f1952

What it tells us is it can be overcome using an [AppContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152167/when-do-we-need-to-use-system-appcontext) switch, so just add this code before any other and it will work:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.IgnoreEmptyKeySequences", true);
```

More on this switch is available here: [Mitigation: XML Schema Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270286.aspx) - note the sentence: "The impact of this change should be minimal" :-)

PS: I believe you can also change these switches using the proper .config file.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware MS is still changing XML parsing. Another question targeting another framework version. Is same code run in my case just with another default value for this switch or is the old code executed?

Comment: No, it's still .NET 4.6, but it takes another path (maybe an old code path, maybe not).